# google search console API regex in searchconsoleR

Tags: r, google-api, google-search-console

is it possible to use regex in searchconsoleR library?

in R i tried to filter all url containing "listing/" (code bellow) but r return "Error in as.character(x) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character' "

my code:

```
dane3 <- search_analytics(siteURL = "https://www.***.**" , 
startDate = "2018-06-01", 
endDate = "2018-06-01", 
dimensions = c("date" , "query" , "page") ,
dimensionFilterExp = grep(".*listing\/.*", page, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE,
      fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate the same error with `grep()` part. My error is `Error: '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "".*listing\/"`, which means `/` is not a character which should be escaped. Check [this doc](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html). So your code should be like this:

```
grep(".*listing/.*", data2$names, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE,
    fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use regex in the filters, the closest you can get is to use `!~` for not contains and `~~` for contains.

e.g. to list pages that contains "blah" use

`page~~blah`